# How to prevent a state change in angular 2/4 project using ui router?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

On user switch to another state or close the page, pop up a window to ask user if they really want to leave the current page.
If the user choose not to leave, prevent the state transition.

Is there a way to do it?

**NOTE:** The project uses **Angular 2/4** and **ui-router.**

I know in angular 1.x you could use `$stateChangeStart` event and do `event.preventDefault()` to stop the state change. Is there anything similar in Angular 2/4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use *UI-ROUTER*'s `TransitionService` and its [`onBefore()`](https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/docs/latest/classes/transition.transitionservice.html#onbefore) method.

As stated on [*UI-ROUTER*'s site](https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/docs/latest/classes/transition.transitionservice.html#onbefore):

> Registers a transition lifecycle hook, which is invoked before a transition even begins. This hook can be useful to implement logic which prevents a transition from even starting, such as authentication, redirection
>
> ...
>
> The hook's return value can be used to pause, cancel, or redirect the current Transition.
>
> ...
>
> false: the transition will be cancelled

Stopping transition:

```
transitionService.onBefore({ to: 'home' }, (trans: Transition) => {
  // put here you conditional logic
  if ('the user choose not to leave') {
    return false;
  }
  // if you want to redirect to different location use:
  // trans.router.stateService.target("home.dashboard"));
});
```

Comment: How to stop the state change? is there something like state.prevent() to stop the state transition?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `unload` or `beforeunload` events like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
  @HostListener('window:unload', [ '$event' ])
  unloadHandler(event) {
    // open popup
  }

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', [ '$event' ])
  beforeUnloadHandler(event) {
    // open popup
  }
}
```